# I set 'state' to '0'. However, nothing appears in the 'state'

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner to study 'react'. I am studying state. I set 'state' to '0'. However, nothing appears in the 'state'. Why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/4j0k03zrm4

Comment: Because you misspelled 'number' in your render method. It says `this.state.nubmer` https://codesandbox.io/s/44qw4y3ow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to React. You're going to love it. :)

As for you problem, you made a typo in the render function. Instead of `<p> number: {this.state.nubmer}</p>` you should write `<p> number: {this.state.number}</p>` (`nubmer` -> `number`).